# Error in UseMethod("family") - multilevel model

Tags: r, lme4

I am currently working on multilevel models. My individual group is "how satisfied a person is" and the other variables are "income feel", "health", working, social, country.

My group level is: countries and density.

I am displaying four different types of models (varying intercepts with no predictors/varying intercepts with individual level predictors/...) and right now I am having problems with the Varying intercepts with group-level predictor model which shows the error as shown in the code below.

```
M3 = lmer(happylyf ~ incomefeel + healthy + workinf + social + density + (1 | country), 
          + family(binomial(link = "logit")),data = Mer)
```

> Error in UseMethod("family") : 
>     no applicable method for 'family' applied to an object of class "family"

This shows the structure of the response

```
str(Mer$happylyf)
# num [1:10977] 4 5 4 4 4 4 2 3 4 4 ...
#1=unhappy (...) 5=very happy
```

Also When I display the Varying intercepts and slopes with group-level predictor model this is what I get.

```
M4 = lmer ( happylyf ~ incomefeel + healthy + workinf + social + 
                       density:incomefeel + density:healthy + density:workinf + density:social +
                (1 + incomefeel + healthy + workinf + social |country), data = Mer)
```

> Warning messages:
>   1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling 
>   2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
>     unable to evaluate scaled gradient
>   3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
>     Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues

Comment: `family=binomial()`, and I think the advice is to use `glmer`, so your model would be `glmer(happylyf ~ incomefeel + healthy + workinf + social + density + (1 | country),  family=binomial(link = "logit") ,data = Mer)`

Comment: Doing this results in an other error:Error in eval(family$initialize, rho) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

Comment: Logistic regression either assumes the response variable is 0/1 : yes/no, etc ..., or is a proportion between 0 and 1, when weights are specified. Is you response of this form? If not, can you add the results of `str(Mer$happylyf)` to your question please.

Comment: No it isn't of this form (so I shouldn't use glmer?). I have added str(Mer$happylyf) to my code what would this be useful for?

Comment: ;) Sorry I meant to edit your question here by adding the results of  `str(Mer$happylyf)` - so we could see its structure. But if your response is not of suitable form, it is unlikely you should be using logistic regression. You may still be able to use glmer, with a different family - but it depends on the distribution of your response.

Comment: thanks for the update. okay, well it looks like you shouldn't be using logistic regression. What do the numbers represent: are they normal numeric? are they counts? are they ordered categories (say from 1 to 5)? However, I think this is moving away from a programming question towards requiring statistical advice, so I think it may be better to ask for advice over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: maybe of interest: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238581/how-to-use-ordinal-logistic-regression-with-random-effects

Comment: Thank you I will look at that. I have edited my question.

Comment: I wouldn't be using lmer for this - your residuals will not be normally distributed. Have a look at the packages at the link. More generally, convergence can be difficult with mixed models (see `?lme4::convergence` for things to try) , however, convergence issues can be due to trying to fit a model too complex, or not suitable for the data - and that model looks quite complicated.